# compare two strings in php and show character differences

Tags: php, string, compare, character, match

Hi I am struggling to get this right:

I want to compare two strings and calculate their score in php.

What that means is I have two strings:

$string1="example1";
$string2="exumple22";

Now I want to compare the strings if they are equal - in this case they are not.

But additionally I want to see the characters that match. At least count them.

In this case that would be: 6;

I have tried this but I am stuck hers is my example:

```
enter code here
<?  
include("connect.php");
$query="SELECT * FROM data where ID = '1'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    //echo "Score :{$row['scoreA']} <br>" ;
    $scoretemp=$row['scoreA'];
    $string1=$row['textA1'];
    $string2=$row['textA2'];


} 
mysql_close();

if (strcmp($string1, $string2) != 0){
    echo "not equal in a case-sensitive string comparison <br>";
$j = strlen($string1);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $j; $i++) {
    $stringtemp1++;
    echo $string1[$i].', ';
    echo $stringtemp1;
    }    

    $u = strlen($string2);
    for ($t = 0; $t < $u; $t++) {
    $stringtemp2++;
    echo $string2[$t].', ';
    echo $stringtemp2;
    }$scoreA=($stringtemp1 - $stringtemp2);    
    $stringtemp1=0;$stringtemp2=0;
}
else{
    echo "Stringmatch! <br>";
        $e = strlen($string1);
        for ($r = 0; $r < $e; $r++) {
        $stringtemp1++;
        echo $string1[$r].', ';
        echo $stringtemp1;
}$scoreA=$stringtemp1;
$stringtemp1=0;
}
 ?>
```

Comment: Can you describe how exactly you are stuck? What specifically is giving you a headache?

Comment: Coud you please reduce your code to only the things that are important for solving your problem?

Answer (score 10):

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php for how to use `similar_text($str1, $str2)`

This will give you the number of matching chars in both strings.

```
<?php
    echo similar_text("Hello World","Hello Peter");
?>
```

will give you 7 (the number of characters in common).

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
<?php

$string1 = 'example1';
$string2 = 'exumple22';

$matchingcharacters = [];
$mismatchingcharacters = [];

$len1 = strlen($string1);
$len2 = strlen($string2);

$similarity = $i = $j = $dissimilarity = 0;

while (($i < $len1) && isset($string2[$j])) {
    if ($string1[$i] == $string2[$j]) {
        $similarity++;
        $matchingcharacters[] = '['.$string1[$i].']';
    } else {
        $dissimilarity++;
        $mismatchingcharacters[] = '['.$string1[$i] . " & " . $string2[$j].']';
    }
    $i++;
    $j++;
}
echo 'First string : '.$string1.'<br>';
echo 'Second string : '.$string2.'<br>';
echo 'Similarity : ' . $similarity . '<br>';
echo 'Dissimilarity : ' . $dissimilarity . '<br>';
echo 'Matching characters : ' . implode(",", $matchingcharacters) . '<br>';
echo 'Mismatching characters : ' . implode(",", $mismatchingcharacters);
```

Comment: This is really good. But I am facing issue when I have variable in the `$string1`, say suppose `$string1 = 'example1 ' . $replaceme;` and when I want to compare, with string 2 , variable should ignore characters upto 10 with $replaceme variable. Can you guide me to do it?

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate the [levenshtein](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) distance between 2 strings:

> In its simplest form the function will take only the two strings as parameter and will calculate just the number of insert, replace and delete operations needed to transform str1 into str2.

Comment: He wants to count the number of matching characters, not the levenshtein distance.

Comment: @js1568, my mistake, he should use similar-text instead

Comment: Hi thank you, similar_text() would only give me a percentage not the exact number of matching characters right?

Comment: No, The similar_text() function returns the number of matching characters of two strings.
It can also calculate the similarity of the two strings in percent.